# get xml or substring value from postgresql table

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I have the folowing as a text in the column my_data with a table my_table (id, my_data)..

```
<gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:geonet="http://www.fao.org/geonetwork">
    <gmd:fileIdentifier>
        <gco:CharacterString>abc1234</gco:CharacterString>
    </gmd:fileIdentifier>
    <gmd:title>
        <gco:CharacterString>Plan_num1</gco:CharacterString>
    </gmd:title>
</gmd:MD_Metadata>
```

I convert the column my_data to xml to try to get the value abc1234 and the value Plan_num1 .. Trying solution found at this forum I was not able to get them (I have 2 name space and I get nothing).. Is-there any solution by using xpath or by using extract string?
Thanks

Comment: I paste the code but i do not see it in my question (sorry)<gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:geonet="http://www.fao.org/geonetwork">
  <gmd:fileIdentifier>
    <gco:CharacterString>abc2301gfh548fh54fh54</gco:CharacterString>
  </gmd:fileIdentifier>
  <gmd:title>
      <gco:CharacterString>Plan_num1</gco:CharacterString>
   </gmd:title>
</gmd:MD_Metadata>

Comment: What solution did you try? What was the result - any error messages? null return values?

Comment: I convert the my_data to xml and tried for exemple SELECT (xpath('/MD_Metadata/fileIdentifier/CharacterString/text()', my_data))[1]::text AS name from my_table; to get the first value abc1234.. but I got no erreur and no data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements you're trying to select in your XPath expression, such as MD_Metadata and fileIdentifier, are each in a namespace. But your XPath expression asks for `/MD_Metadata`, which means 'an element named MD_Metadata that is in no namespace'. So your XPath expression doesn't select the elements you're looking for.

In order to select `MD_Metadata` in the namespace whose URI is "http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd", you need to map a prefix to that namespace, use the prefix in your XPath expression, and pass the mapping to Postgres via a third argument to your `xpath()` function.

E.g.

```
SELECT (xpath('/gmd:MD_Metadata/fmd:fileIdentifier/gco:CharacterString/text()',
  my_data, ARRAY[ARRAY['gmo', 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd'],
                ARRAY['gco', 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco']]))[1]::text
    AS name from my_table;
```

I'm not sure what you intend with the `[1]`, whether you mean it to be part of the XPath expression or not.

See http://www.edankert.com/defaultnamespaces.html (the first two sections) to better understand the nature of the problem in XML/namespaces/XPath.

See section 9.14.3, [Processing XML](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-xml.html) for documentation on doing this with `xpath()` in PostgreSQL.

Comment: thanks alot.. it's works... I got {abc1234}.. How can I get the same value ..without {}.. thanks again

Comment: it's me again ... it is ok.. with [1]::text  I got the information without the {}..